# How to access XML file present at client side?

Tags: xml, web-services

We have a web service which writes to an XML file. We are generating WSDL on one machine and parsing it on a different one, but when we write or read the XML file , the file present on the machine where we generated the WSDL is getting accessed.

We want to access the file present on the machine where we parse the WSDL. 
We have already tried with .properties way.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your code. Give us a clue, show us some code.